# Respect\Validation\Validator - using an array while catching errors

Tags: validation, fat-free-framework, respect-validation

I am attempting to catch errors utilizing the [Respect\Validation\Validator](https://github.com/Respect/Validation) opensource PHP class.  I used their example to create an array of checks.  Although that seems to work ok, I then attempted to catch any error messages so that I could display it to the user.  I saw no method to do so as a full array (check everything, store all messages in an array).  So instead, I tried to cycle through using the check method in Validator.

This is inside of a class method, using the F3 (Fat Free) Framework.

I end up with the following error:

> Cannot use object of type Respect\Validation\Validator as array

The code is below.  What is the proper way to perform this task using arrays here?  Thank you for the assistance!

```
$registerValidator = 
    Respect\Validation\Validator::attribute('email', Respect\Validation\Validator::email()->length(1,null)->notEmpty())
        ->attribute('address', Respect\Validation\Validator::stringType()->length(3,null)->notEmpty())
        ->attribute('city', Respect\Validation\Validator::alpha()->length(2,60)->notEmpty())
        ->attribute('state', Respect\Validation\Validator::alpha()->length(2,2)->notEmpty())
        ->attribute('zip', Respect\Validation\Validator::intType()->length(5,5)->notEmpty());
    
foreach($this->f3->get('POST') as $key => $value){
    try{
        $registerValidator[$key]->check($value);
    } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        $errors = $e->getMainMessage();
        $this->userMessage($errors, 'warning');
        $this->f3->reroute('/register');
    }
}
```

I have also tried to use the assert method as found in their docs, but utilizing the below change, I get a different error at a 500 Server Internal Error, instead of seeing my echo:

```
try{
    $registerValidator->assert($this->f3->get('POST'));
} catch (Respect\Validation\Validator\NestedValidationException $e) {
    $errors = $e->getMessages();
    echo($errors); // I can't even get here.
    foreach($errors as $error){
        $this->userMessage($error, 'warning');
    }
    $this->f3->reroute('/register');
}
```

With this 500 Error, rather than seeing my Echo, so the page stops loading entirely.

> All of the required rules must pass for ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot really use the `Validator` class as an array like you're doing on `$registerValidator[$key]->check($value)`. The object in `$registerValidator` variable contain the chain of rules to validate an **input**.

In your case I believe the **input** is the array coming from the  `POST`, so first of all you should use the [Key](http://respect.github.io/Validation/docs/key.html) validator instead of [Attribute](http://respect.github.io/Validation/docs/attribute.html).

However the real reason why you cannot catch the errors is because you have a typo on your `catch` statement, the class name should be `Respect\Validation\Exceptions\NestedValidationException` like it's stated in the documentation, not `Respect\Validation\Validator\NestedValidationException`.